# How to plot linebr with text in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

[image]

like this but not ray and also move the text to right

I had tried putting

```
timenow + math.round(ta.change(time) )
```

in X in label.new but it shows this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bar_index` for simplicity.

Create a `var` `line` and `label` and update their `x`, `y,` and `text` on each bar.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

var line prev_close_line = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right)
var label prev_close_lbl = label.new(na, na, na, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.green)

line.set_xy1(prev_close_line, bar_index, close[1])
line.set_xy2(prev_close_line, bar_index+1, close[1])
label.set_xy(prev_close_lbl, bar_index, close[1])
label.set_text(prev_close_lbl, str.tostring(close[1]))
```

[image]